# mvn release plugin won't update next dev version

Tags: maven, version, release, maven-release-plugin

I am performing a maven release using the release plugin. It works all fine and uploads my artifact as well but the final commit which is supposed to update the next development version is marking the dev version in the pom as below
`<version>${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0-SNAPSHOT</version>`

This is my release plugin configuration

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <checkModificationExcludes>
                        <checkModificationExclude>pom.xml</checkModificationExclude>
                    </checkModificationExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Any idea why this is happening? The console output shows the following

```
14:04:15 Executing Maven:  -B -f /unpcommon-ankr-3147/workspace/UNP Jar Builder - non parameterized/ncprocessorcommon/pom.xml -DdevelopmentVersion=1.2.1-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=1.2.0 -Dresume=false release:clean release:prepare release:perform

14:04:16 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
14:04:16 [WARNING] 
14:04:16 [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.paypal.notification.common:ncprocessorcommon:jar:${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0-SNAPSHOT
14:04:16 [WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ line 11, column 14
14:04:16 [WARNING] 
14:04:16 [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
14:04:16 [WARNING] 
14:04:16 [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

Comment: The content `${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0-SNAPSHOT` looks like something for buildnumber plugin given but not for real working versions...

Comment: @khmarbaise What do you mean? Upon performing a maven release we provide the next development version for maven to update in the pom post the release. It's not parsing that version correctly and in turn is committing the unparsed variables.

Comment: Please show your full pom file... furthermore those things are not parsed by the maven-release-plugin ...